# How to copy a segment within a line of a text file into a list

Tags: python

How would I be able to iterate through each line of a text file and copy the author's name into a list using Python? The text file I am working with contains the following quotes with the authors' names at the end of each quote:

> ```
> Power tends to corrupt and absolute power corrupts absolutely. --- Lord Acton
> No man means all he says, and yet very few say all they mean, for words are slippery and thought is viscous. --- Henry B. Adams
> One friend in a lifetime is much; two are many; three are hardly possible. --- Henry B. Adams
> ```

Comment: Which part of that are you struggling with? Opening the file? Iterating over the lines? Parsing the line to extract the author's name? Putting the name into a list?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification. Im struggling with parsing the line to extract the authors name.

Comment: Then you should post the code that does the other aspects, your attempt to parse the line and a description of precisely what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
authors_list = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        text = line.rstrip('\n').split(" --- ")
        if len(text) > 1:
            authors_list.append(text[1])
```

Comment: You don't need `f.close()` with `with`, and `'r'` is the default for `open`.

Comment: @miindlek I have got more quotes, unlike the examples i have provided, some of them occupy more than one line meaning the for line in f statement would not work. How would i go about dealing with this ?

Comment: @user116284 Could you post some example?

Comment: @miindlek e.g.I must not fear. Fear is the mind-killer. Fear is the little-death that brings total obliteration. I will face my fear. I will permit it to pass over me and through me. And when it has gone past I will turn the inner eye to see its path. Where the fear has gone there will be nothing. Only I will remain. --- Frank Herbert

Comment: @miindlek how would i parse this quote if it occupies more than 1 line in the text file ?

Comment: @ user116284 use readlines(), all lines are read into a list and then split by a delimiter which in this case is '\n'. here is the output of reading the code with readlines()     [' Lord Acton', ' Henry B. Adams', ' Henry B. Adams', ' Frank Herbert']

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions, you could do it as follows:

```
import re
import string

with open('text.txt') as f:
    txt = f.readlines()

authors = re.findall('(?<=---).*?(?=\n)', '\n'.join(txt))
authors = map(string.strip, authors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generator based solution for a bit of fun:

```py
# Generate stream manipulators
def strip(stream):
    """Strips whitespace from stream entries"""

    for entry in stream:
        yield entry.strip()

def index(i, stream):
    """Takes the i-th element from the stream entries"""

    for entry in stream:
        yield entry[i]

def split(token, stream):
    """Splits the entries in the stream based based on the token"""

    for entry in stream:
        yield entry.split(token)

# Actual function to do the work
def authors(filename):
    """Returns a list of the authors from the file format"""

    for entry in strip(index(1, split('---', open(filename)))):
        yield entry

print list(authors('file.txt'))
```

Generator/filtering/pipeline based solutions can be good for this sort of task.

Answer (score -1):

the below peice should work too. readlines() reads and loads the complete file into memory , be careful about using it when you have large files though. For smaller ones this should be quite OK.

```
n = []
with open('test1.txt') as fd:
    lines = fd.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        n.append( line.split('---')[1].strip('\n'))

print n
```

output:
    [' Lord Acton', ' Henry B. Adams', ' Henry B. Adams']

Comment: Can not see any major difference to my solution, except that your solution raises an exception, if the line doesn't contain any '---'.

Comment: yup, its just another way of reading file using readlines() rather than from the file object, but agreed reading from file object is much quicker.